# How can I put these buttons in PyQt5 on top of each other?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would like these buttons to be stacked neatly but I cannot find a way to do it.

[image]

Provided below is the snippet of code from this specific tab that I am working on.

```
        # Create Buttons for Tab 2
        self.generate_lru_notes = QPushButton("Generate LRU Report")
        self.generate_lru_notes.setToolTip("Click me to Generate the LRU Report")
        self.generate_lru_notes.setFixedWidth(200)

        self.clear_lru_notes = QPushButton("Clear LRU Report Data")
        self.clear_lru_notes.setToolTip("Click me to Clear the LRU Report")
        self.clear_lru_notes.setFixedWidth(200)

        # Create Labels and Text Edits for tab 2
        self.lbl_investigation_notes = QLabel("LRU Investigation Notes: ")
        self.txt_investigation_notes = QTextEdit()
        self.txt_investigation_notes.setFixedWidth(350)
        self.txt_investigation_notes.setFixedHeight(150)

        self.lbl_rework_notes = QLabel("LRU Rework Notes: ")
        self.txt_rework_notes = QTextEdit()
        self.txt_rework_notes.setFixedWidth(350) 
        self.txt_rework_notes.setFixedHeight(150)

        self.lbl_sc_investigation_notes = QLabel("Sub-Component Investigation Notes: ")
        self.txt_sc_investigation_notes = QTextEdit()
        self.txt_sc_investigation_notes.setFixedWidth(350)
        self.txt_sc_investigation_notes.setFixedHeight(150)

        self.lbl_sc_rework_notes = QLabel("Sub-Component Rework Notes")
        self.txt_sc_rework_notes = QTextEdit()
        self.txt_sc_rework_notes.setFixedWidth(350)
        self.txt_sc_rework_notes.setFixedHeight(150)

        self.lbl_ad_sc_inv_notes = QLabel ("Additional Sub-Component Investigation Notes: ")
        self.txt_ad_sc_inv_notes = QTextEdit()
        self.txt_ad_sc_inv_notes.setFixedWidth(350)
        self.txt_ad_sc_inv_notes.setFixedHeight(150)

        self.lbl_ad_sc_rework_notes = QLabel("Additonal Sub-Component Rework Notes: ")
        self.txt_ad_sc_rework_notes = QTextEdit()
        self.txt_ad_sc_rework_notes.setFixedWidth(350)
        self.txt_ad_sc_rework_notes.setFixedHeight(150)

        # Add the form elements to the first Grid in Tab 2
        self.t2_grid1 = QGridLayout()
        self.t2_grid1.setSpacing(0)
        self.t2_grid1.setRowStretch(50, 1)
        self.t2_grid1.setColumnStretch(50, 1)
        self.t2_grid1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # Add the form elements to the second Grid in Tab 2
        self.t2_grid2 = QGridLayout()
        self.t2_grid2.setSpacing(0)
        self.t2_grid2.setRowStretch(50, 1)
        self.t2_grid2.setColumnStretch(50, 1)
        self.t2_grid2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # Add the form elements to the third Grid in Tab 2
        self.t2_grid3 = QGridLayout()
        self.t2_grid3.setSpacing(1)
        self.t2_grid3.setRowStretch(50, 1)
        self.t2_grid3.setColumnStretch(50, 1)
        self.t2_grid3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # Add the form elements to the fourth Grid on Tab 2.

        self.t2_grid4 = QGridLayout()
        self.t2_grid4.setSpacing(0)
        self.t2_grid4.setRowStretch(50, 1)
        self.t2_grid4.setColumnStretch(50, 1)
        self.t2_grid4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # Grid 1 for Tab 2
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.lbl_investigation_notes, 0, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.txt_investigation_notes, 1, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.lbl_rework_notes, 0, 2, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.txt_rework_notes, 1, 2, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.generate_lru_notes, 1, 3, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.clear_lru_notes, 2, 3, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft)

        # Grid 3 for Tab 2
        self.t2_grid3.addWidget(self.lbl_sc_investigation_notes, 0, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid3.addWidget(self.txt_sc_investigation_notes, 1, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid3.addWidget(self.lbl_sc_rework_notes, 0, 2, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop| Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid3.addWidget(self.txt_sc_rework_notes, 1, 2, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)

        # Grid 4 for Tab 2
        self.t2_grid4.addWidget(self.lbl_ad_sc_inv_notes, 0, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid4.addWidget(self.txt_ad_sc_inv_notes, 1, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid4.addWidget(self.lbl_ad_sc_rework_notes, 0, 2, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.t2_grid4.addWidget(self.txt_ad_sc_rework_notes, 1, 2, 1, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom)

        # Set the layout for the LRU Info tab
        self.tab2_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.tab2)
        self.tab2_layout.addLayout(self.t2_grid1)
        self.tab2_layout.addLayout(self.t2_grid2)
        self.tab2_layout.addLayout(self.t2_grid3)
        self.tab2_layout.addLayout(self.t2_grid4)
```

I have tried to align the Buttons in the same column but different rows, however the other widgets in the same grid are affecting the spacing I believe. I have thought about creating another grid but the way this tabs layout is setup the buttons would be below where I want them to be, unless someone has a better explanation?

Comment: What do you mean by 'stacked'. Should both buttons be visible at the same time, or should only one be visible but be switchable with the other. In the latter case you can put them in a `QStackedLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `rowSpan` argument of `addWidget()` for the text edits, so that they can occupy two lines in the layout, and then *properly* use `setRowStretch` (it seems like you're inverting the argument, and the row is wrong) for the bottom line, so that it will expand vertically.

Also note that:

- you should only use the `alignment` argument when you specifically need it, and, in any case, with *valid* values (`Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignBottom` doesn't make any sense);
- the `setColumnStretch()` is also wrong, if you want to align the layout to the left, use `layout.setAlignment()`;
- there's no point in specifying the row and column span if both are going to be `1`;

```py
        self.t2_grid1 = QGridLayout()
        self.t2_grid1.setSpacing(0)
        self.t2_grid1.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        self.t2_grid1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.t2_grid1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        ...
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.lbl_investigation_notes, 0, 0)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.txt_investigation_notes, 1, 0, 2, 1)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.lbl_rework_notes, 0, 2)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.txt_rework_notes, 1, 2, 2, 1)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.generate_lru_notes, 1, 3, Qt.AlignTop)
        self.t2_grid1.addWidget(self.clear_lru_notes, 2, 3, Qt.AlignTop)
```

I suggest you to take some time and play around with Qt Designer in order to easily understand the relations between different widget types and how they are managed in layouts.

Comment: Thanks. This helped clean up my code. It didn't necessarily point me in the exact direction I was looking for but I ended up changing my buttons to align themselves on the top and bottom (respectively) in the cell and then I changed their height to 75 so that combined they will occupy the same row and column without any issues (so far). I will spend more time tinkering in the Qt Designer I have just been putting around with the actual code. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Barnesz Are you saying that you added the buttons to the same layout cell and used different alignments/heights in order to make them occupy the cell height? Why? That doesn't make a lot of sense, and it's also terribly wrong: first of all, the whole point of spanning is to solve these needs (and even if you don't want to use it for some reason, you could just add a vbox layout to the cell in which you want the buttons, and add them to that layout instead), but doing that could actually make buttons overlap in certain situations, and that's is bad, especially if done for the wrong reasons.

Comment: yes I set the fixed height of each button as 75, since I know that my textEdits are at a fixed height of 150. So the cell and rows that are being occupied by the textEdits are 150 in height, unless what you're saying is that the row spanning will prevent the textEdits from affecting other rows in that grid? I'm sorry I am still learning Python and PyQt specifically so I'm figuring it out as I go. Do not have the time nor money to get official training so i'm fumbling around myself. Here is the source code after my edits https://pastebin.com/RCkyvU3d

Comment: @Barnesz Learning on your own is fine, even if sometimes it's a bit painful, and in any case requires lots of time and patience. While trial and error is effective, don't leave everything to it, as studying the documentation is *always* a good choice, especially when it's well written as that of Qt is, which is above the average level and very reliable, except for rare cases (nobody is perfect, and we're talking about a toolkit that counts *hundreds* of classes and thousands of functions) so always consider them, using the official C++ API as main reference (even if you use Python).

Comment: @Barnesz Yes, the row spanning of the text edits will prevent any effect on the other rows in *that* same grid layout, as long as you don't put other widgets with different spanning and that have size policies that may be incompatible with the way you're laying out widgets. Note that if you want to ensure that the buttons occupy as much vertical space as possible (so that they occupy all the available space in their grid cell), you must change their [size policy](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html): eg. `self.generate_lru_notes.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)`